# jquery not firing

Tags: jquery

hi my intention is to add a div element on the click of a button.

here is my code

```
$(function() {

$("#add").live("click",function(event) {

$(this).append('<div>CHID</div>'); // the text is supplied between the div tags

});

});
```

add is the name of the button.. i ve made sure that i ve correctly included the jquery library. I dunt know where i am going wrong. can anyone help me..

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/V8vZG/

Comment: @jamie . its not fine here :( i ve included jquery from google api. a simple alert inside my function works.. but i cannot see the text appearing

Comment: Are you including it from the CDN jquery, or using `google.load`?

Comment: i included it using CDN jquery.. it worked fine after i changed append to work since we cannot append to input elements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#add` searches for the id of an element not the name, check this

EDIT: I read your comment. Try `.after()` rather than `.append()`

Comment: i ve give both name and id as add. This is my line                      <input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="click"/>

Comment: thank u mauro. it works after changing append to after.. but i dunt know why is that happening

Comment: You can't put a div inside an input element. This is why it isn't working.

Comment: append will work fine for exemple if you want to add an option to a select, which is not your case. For a correct understanding I'll suggest a brief look at some manual on HTML DOM. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is this code executing after the document is ready?

Append inserts the object as a child node. In this case, the  node should probably be a sibling. You can use .after() rather than .append().

Comment: cheers jthomspon. when i changed append to after it works.. pls may i know y?

Comment: <input> elements should not have child nodes. So, if you use .after it is inserted in the document at the same level of the input. This may or may not be what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

is #add is button? if it isn't, try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#add").click(function(){
  $(this).append('<div>CHID</div>');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have two issues here. First is that `#add` looks for the ID of the element, not the name. The second is that `$(this)` will reference your button - not your document.

Make sure you have the `ID` attribute set on the button and change the `$(this)` reference to something like `$("body")` or `$("#myContainer")` to add a div to the body or other container element.

Comment: thank u Jonathon. ur solution worked. also in my code when i changed append to after it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a div inside an input element. So if you are using an input element:

```
<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="click"/>
```

it is impossible to append divs inside it.